# Unable to deploy a Ec2Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am trying to create ECS Service and point Application Balancer to it but it just stuck on creating Ec2Service

```js
const cluster = new Cluster(this, `TestCluster`, {
    vpc: vpc,
    clusterName: `TestCluster`,
});
// Add capacity to it
const autoScalingGroup = new AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ASG', {
    vpc,
    instanceType: new InstanceType('t2.micro'),
    machineImage: EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(),
    minCapacity: 1,
    maxCapacity: 2,
});
const capacityProvider = new AsgCapacityProvider(this, 'AsgCapacityProvider', {
    autoScalingGroup,
});
const dockerFile = `./build/auth/`;
const dockerImageAsset = new DockerImageAsset(stackRef, `authDockerImage`, {
    directory: dockerFile,
});

// create task defination
const taskDefinition = new Ec2TaskDefinition(stackRef, `authTaskDefination`, {
    networkMode: NetworkMode.AWS_VPC
});

//add container
const container = taskDefinition.addContainer('AuthContainer', {
    image: ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(dockerImageAsset),
    memoryLimitMiB: 512,

    logging: LogDrivers.awsLogs({
        streamPrefix: `authService`,
        logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_DAY
    }),
    containerName: `auth`,
    portMappings: [{
        containerPort: 80
    }],

});


//create taskService
const service = new Ec2Service(stackRef, `${taskName}TaskService`, {
    cluster: cluster,
    taskDefinition: taskDefinition
});
```

if I remove `Ec2Service` and use `FargateService` its deployed successfully, I tried several times but it just got stuck on deploying EC2Service

Comment: What do you mean by capacity, do you mean memoryLimitMiB or cpu?

Comment: It's been years since I've done ECS, but how are you bootstrapping your nodes? I recall the bootstrap script at least requiring you pass the cluster name so the instance knows which cluster it's a part of, but I don't see any userdata in your post.

Comment: I would start by trying to find the detail of the error ECS is encountering: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html And also, as jordanm suggested, verify that the EC2 instance(s) are showing up as registered instances in the ECS cluster.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks you were right it was memory issue +Applicaltion balancer Proxy issue

Answer (score 0):

It was memory issue + ENI issue due to which service never get deployed